# Integrating Windows Product Key into Windows 8 RTM ISO

Tags: windows-8, unattended

Many years ago I created a slipstreamed version of Windows XP with my product key embedded in an unattended set-up file that was in the disk/ISO.

I have been struggling to find out where or how I can integrate my key into the RTM version ISO for Windows 8. Does anyone know how I can do this with Windows 8?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Windows 8 has not been released yet.  This will be possible.  The tools used to do this simply have to be updated by their respected authors.

Comment: @Ramhound, Windows 8 has been released to all MSDN members, so we can use it right now.

Comment: Yes PhonicUK, you are correct. I have an MSDN account and access to the RTM ISO for Windows 8.

Comment: @PhonicUK - I am more then aware of that. The author of this question of course will have to wait for those tools to be updated.  They could also write their own I suppose.  All the documentation of course might not have been released, I do remember a blog entry from Microsoft on this very subject also a Zdnet article.

Comment: @Ramhound see Moab's answer. Your posts in this thread have been completely incorrect and totally misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Use the WSIM tool Windows 8 ADK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30652) to configure the Answer file

[ADK documents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825420.aspx)

Comment: thanks Moab. This has also lead me to another useful tool which is the  Windows System Imager